# Apple Watch: How to create Group with multiple rows?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

When dragging a button to a group, it's not letting me drag it to the second row. Instead it forces me to drag it to the first row outside of the visible area. How do I fix this so that it's a grid of 3x3?

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single group will use either an horizontal or a vertical layout, but not both simultaneously. So, to create a grid, you should use nested groups. As an example I'm showing an outer, vertical, group and three nested horizontal ones.

[image]

You can find out more at the [Apple Watch HiG](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/)